# How to get checked value by cfloop in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion-8

How can I get the checked values from some checkboxes using cfloop in coldfusion?

The checkboxes are created dynamically from a database query. ie:

```
<cfloop query="GetDataMaterial">
    <input type="checkbox" name="MaterialID" value="#MaterialID#" />
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form field will contain a comma-separated list of all values that are checked with the same form name.

For instance:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MaterialID" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="MaterialID" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="MaterialID" value="4">
<input type="checkbox" name="MaterialID" value="8">
<input type="checkbox" name="MaterialID" value="16">
<input type="checkbox" name="MaterialID" value="32">
```

If the user Checks all of them, you'll get, assuming your form does a post:

```
form.MaterialID: "1,2,4,8,16,32"
```

If the user checks the first and last, you'll get

```
form.MaterialID: "1,32"
```

So, if you want to loop over them, you can

```
<cfloop list="#form.MaterialId#">
  ...
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to have index="i" and use it to loop through the list of checkbox

```
<cfloop list="#form.MaterialId#" index="i">
<cfoutput>#i#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```